# Can we get a fixed rate of kWH to USD through bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory

Assuming the energy to bitcoin rate of your choosing, what is the cost of one kiloWatt Hour, in USD?

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming the energy to bitcoin rate of your choosing

Market questions generally go out of date extremely quickly, and Bitcoin mining in general varies hugely in efficiency and availability of hardware. It is not as clear cut as working out the hardware level of efficiency at the chip level as this is only a small portion of the total power cost.

- At a chip level, the hash engines have a specific cost per hash, minus any amount of failure rate, which is generally in the order of several percent of the work wasted.
- At a miner level, where it converts incoming high voltage AC mains power to a lower voltage for use with the mining chips. This varies greatly with the design of the hardware being used, from tens of percent to just a few depending on the complexity and cost of the conversion.
- At a farm level, where incoming transmission voltage is converted to mains voltage. This varies massively depending if the incoming supply is already designed for residential use (120v/240v), industrial use (277v/480v), or commercial distribution (tens or hundreds of kilovolts), and the efficiency of the hardware used.

It's therefor pretty hard to define even a cost per hashrate in the wider network, but once you know it it's relatively straightforward to convert it to a USD cost.

> what is the cost of one kiloWatt Hour, in USD

This is the simple bit. They're usually specified literally as this price, for example in parts of north america 4c/kWh is fairly typical, but it varies extremely widely betwene location and provider anywhere from 1c to 35c.

Answer (score -1):

This question is a bit vague, however if you're interested in energy expenditure cost there are many good articles on the macro view of Bitcoin mining costs. I've linked one below that is quite comprehensive.

[Digesting ‘Quantification of energy and carbon costs for mining cryptocurrencies’](https://medium.com/@nic__carter/digesting-quantification-of-energy-and-carbon-costs-for-mining-cryptocurrencies-1f019e10fad4)

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged because they go out of date, and don’t really give an answer as such.